# Organize in chunks of size M - MapReduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

Let's say I have a dataset like below:

```
0,0,A
0,1,B
0,2,C
1,4,D
9,5,E
1,3,O
4,4,L
7,8,Z
```

I want to implement a MapReduce job so that I group these in chunks of size M. Lets say M=4 then I want a file in the output like:

```
0,0,A;0,1,B;0,2,C;1,4,D
9,5,E;1,3,O;4,4,L;7,8,Z
```

I am worried that this might not be possible cause values in reducer are grouped by a common key which does not exist in this scenario.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You could create your own key while reading the file in the mapper

Comment: @cricket_007 i used the inputsplit to create the key for the data. But if M is small wont I have a problem with the number of mappers? Is there a limit to the mappers I can have?

Comment: I've seen jobs with thousands of mappers, but in general Hadoop doesn't like small files anyway. You're limited by memory more than strictly number of mappers

Comment: @cricket_007 Ok I should give you the big picture. The reason I want to do these is to implement some sort of STR packing for an RTree index by exploiting the parallelism of MapReduce. Is it possible this way or am I limited by the specs of my cluster?

Comment: Input splits should work too